# How to grab textarea data using thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, thymeleaf

I have an array with fields, of which I've output onto html using textareas so that a user can edit them and save them again.

I can set the data using a set method I have, but I'm not sure how to get the textarea text the user entered to pass it into the method. I'm using Thymeleaf also.

```
<td>
   <textarea name = "fitNumber" class="form-control input-sm" rows="1"
                                    th:value="${fit.setFitNumber(Need value set here)}">
   </textarea>
</td>
```

**Edit**

I'll rephrase a little, as it reads incorrectly.

Can you pass a variable within a setter in Thymeleaf. 
e.g. `${person.setName(name)}`

also, can that argument being passed be the text within a `<textarea></textarea>`?

I'm not sure how to get the textarea text and pass it inside a setter method within thymeleaf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a ways to go for this... you need to read up on creating thymeleaf forms (and maybe the whole spring MVC process).

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form

In answer to your question, should be using a form that looks like this:

```
<form th:object="${fit}">
    <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="1" th:field="*{fitNumber}" />
</form>
```

th:object in combination with th:field automatically binds the value of the textarea to your object when you submit the form -- when you submit the form, spring will call fit.setFitNumber(*value from input area*) behind the scenes and your controller method will have the fit object passed to it as a parameter.

Comment: This was really useful. I'm still very new to Spring and especially Thymeleaf. I'll read the documentation around it all.

Comment: I was struggling to get the textarea value back if there is any error & th:field="*{fitNumber}"  works well. Thank you @Metroids

Answer (score 1):

Use `th:field` , that is auto set into the `textarea`

Comment: edited to include a (hopefully) more concise question.

Comment: ${@person.setName('test')}