# Getting values from textarea in html

Tags: thymeleaf

Is value attribute invalid with textarea? if it is invalid, how can I get the value?

I am using thymeleaf, have tried th:value:"${book.title}", but is not returning the input by user.

Any advice?

Comment: `textarea` does not have a value attribute. Value of a `textarea` works as inner HTML.

Comment: how would you get the value of out of textarea?

Comment: try with th:text or th:utext

Comment: I have tried, it doesn't work with th:text or th:utext

Comment: @Learner `th:field = "${content}"` probably if you use it in some form. Another option is probably to use inline notation `<textarea>[[${content}]]</textarea>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grab textarea data using thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613434/how-to-grab-textarea-data-using-thymeleaf)

Comment: @varren it works! thank you!